# How to read images randomly from assets/images folder in angular5

Tags: angular5

I have some images stored in assets/images folder and I want to read them randomly from angular5 code. Could anyone please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: so each time you want to get one randomly chosen picture?

Comment: @maha yes maha on each page load I want random images

Comment: i guess you can name the pictures "img1" and "img2" and so on for all the pictured, then in your code generate a random integer that is less than the number of pictures, and in the html code bind the img name with the string of "img"+"the number you generated"

Comment: @maha How would I get the count of images exists in folder?

Comment: keep getting the photos in a try catch with a counter and in the catch part the count will be the size